# FEA of Rectangular Body Under the Effects of Combined Rotational and Translational Shear

Tags: finite-element-method, mechanical, shear

[image: Fusion360 Static Analysis - Rectangular Beam and Clasp]
[image: Fusion360 Static Analysis - Rectangular Beam Hidden]
[image: Fusion360 Static Analysis - Model of Adhesive Between Beam and Clasp]

First image is model setup. Clasp is rigidly constrained at top surface. Rectangular beam is affixed to clasp at clasp faces (locally constrained), by way of adhesive pads (second and third images).

Arbitrary transverse load (50N) applied at tip of beam, aim of load is to generate torque and rotational shear about clasp at adhesive, as well as translational load and shear again at clasp and adhesive.

Stress revealed through analysis is highly concentrated at upper corners of adhesive and nowhere else.. while expectation was a rotational shear pattern. Why does the simulation of stress show the unexpected pattern?

Comment: Does the concentration lessen or disappear if the pads are made circular? If so, then the issue arises because the corners (being at the end of a rectangle with aspect ratio other than one) need to change shape to rotate while also staying rotationally symmetric. This results in warping.

Comment: The stress concentrations appear around the circumference in the case of circular pads.. But with respect to the "warping" explanation, wouldn't we expect to see the warping on all four corners of the rectangle?

Comment: There are overlying stress effects from the vertical asymmetry. The clasp is more compliant at the bottom than the top, for example.